# working on a onsubmit

Tags: javascript

I am working on a form. I need to have a  onsubmit form handler. And to create a validation script to make sure the fields are not empty. When I go to this when I click the submit form nothing happens. Something should pop up letting me know i didnt fill something out. Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>RSVP</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function verify() {
var themessage = "You are required to complete the following fields: ";
if (document.form.first.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " - First Name";
 }
if (document.form.last.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Last Name";
}
if (document.form.NumberofGuest.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Number of guest";
}
if (document.form.TimeArriving.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  Time Arriving";
}
if (document.form.email.value=="") {
themessage = themessage + " -  E-mail";
}
//alert if fields are empty and cancel form submit
if (themessage == "You are required to complete the following fields: ") {
document.form.submit();
 }
else {
alert(themessage);
return false;
   }

 Function confirmSubmit(){
var submitForm=window.confirm("Are you sure you want to submit the form?");
if (submitForm == true)
return true;
return false;
  }
  function confirmReset(){
  var resetForm = windows.confirm("Are you sure you want to reset the form?");
  if (resetForm == true)
  return true;
  return false;
   }

  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
 <h2>**RSVP to my Party**</h2>
 <form  name=form method="post" action="mailto:sha1023012@yahoo.com?cc=sha1023102@yahoo.com, subject=RSVP"  enctype="text/plain" onsubmit="return confirmSubmit();" onreset="return confirmReset();">
 <input type=text name="first" size="20"> First Name<BR>
 <input type=text name="last" size="20"> Last Name<BR>

<input type=text name="NumberofGuest" size="20"> Number of Guest<BR>
<input type=text name="TimeArriving" size="20"> Time Arriving<BR>
<input type=text name="email" size="20"> E-Mail<BR><BR>
<input type=button value="Submit Request" onclick="verify();">

<input type=reset value="Clear Form"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make note that:

```
if (themessage == "You are required to complete the following fields: ") {
```

will return false if `themessage` equals anything more than just that; which means it will always fail. I recommend, instead, you do something else to determine if there are unfilled fields, like a boolean value (a `var` holding *true* or *false*.) It will cause duplicate code, but I'm sure it can be re-factored in a way where it won't, like using if/else chains.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript is case sensitive.

Change this:

```
Function confirmSubmit(){
```

To this instead:

```
function confirmSubmit(){
```

With your current code you simply get *syntax error* so there's nothing running upon sumission.

Answer (score -1):

You should set the attribute `action` to `action="javascript:"` to avoid the default form submit.

Then set your button as `type="submit"` instead of `button`

And finally set the action as an `onclick` on the submit button. When the user hit enter or click the submit button, the event will fire.

Comment: The only time you should use `javascript:` scheme URIs is when writing bookmarklets. They go completely against the principles of progressive enhancement. Linking JS to a form submission should (unless it matters *which* button was pressed) be done with the submit event on the form, not the click event on a button (so it will still fire if submitted through another mechanism (such as enter in a text input)).

Comment: @David, for your information typing enter in a field works fine the way I describe here. And bringing the "progressive enhancement principle" here while we talk about javascript is quite inappropriate.

Comment: No, click events only work when the button is triggered rather than any time the form is submitted. And progressive enhancement is a cornerstone of well engineered JavaScript, there is nothing inappropriate about mentioning it in a JS discussion.

Comment: Just done a couple of checks, and it seems to work after all. I wouldn't trust it cross browser or in more complex test cases, and it isn't as logical as using the submit event.