# Javascript and HTML function issue

Tags: javascript, html

```
<script stylesheet="text/javascript">
var statename;
function confirmReview(formObj){
    function myState( val ){
        statename = val;
        alert( "This is " + statename );
    }
    postcode = document.getElementById("postcode");
    //Folowing code
    if( statename== "Selangor" ){
          if( postcode < 10000 || postcode > 40000 )
                alert( "Invalid postcode for " + statename );
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<form name = reviewform onsubmit="return confirmReview(reviewform)" method=POST>
    <select id='state' onchange="myState(this.value);">
         <option>Specify state or territory</option>
         <option value="Selangor">Selangor</option>
         <option value="Terengganu">Terengganu</option>
    </select>
</form>
</body>
```

my question is how to store the value and save it to the statename as i fail to run in my HTML javascript code. can anyone teach?

i cannot print out my statename example if i want to make some comparison for my postcode
when i load the script it run to the funciton . my HTML will just clear all the data like refresh the page without showing anything

after i edited the things senior suggested . it's still same. it cannot go to the alert that validation code with the statename

Comment: Where exactly do you want to store the value? In a javascript variable on the same page, or on the server for future reference?

Comment: well your code is right , all you have to do is to wrap javascript in script tags

Comment: Please use uppercase i's and start sentences with uppercase letters. And use a more descriptive title? Thanks!

Comment: already edited. can u see the latest version/?

Comment: Your edits did not change things like *"my question is"* into the proper *"My question is"*, nor changed *"as i fail"* into *"as I fail"*. And PLEASE, write *"can you"* instead of *"can u"*. Thanks! Also, the title is still not describing the problem at all, but I guess it's difficult to describe the problem as it's actually to broad for this site. Questions like yours are not really suitable for a Q&A site like Stack Overflow is.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the script tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var statename;
function myState( val ){
   statename = val;          
}
postcode = document.getElementById("postcode");
</script>
```

Comment: @alex23 oops, sorry, forgot about that xD. Thanks for editing :)

Comment: @alex23 — If there are any such browsers, they are no longer in use. Browsers have defaulted to assuming JS forever and HTML 5 makes the attribute explicitly optional.

Comment: i cannot print out my statename example if i want to make some comparison for my postcode example

Comment: i cannot print out my statename example if i want to make some comparison for my postcode example
     if( statename == "Pinang"" ){
          if( postcode < 10000 || postcode > 40000 )
                  alert( "Invalid postcode ! Re-enter" );
     }

when i load my html . when i run to that function then my HTML will auto refresh to all clear data . cnanot come out that alert. can someone tell me?

Comment: @Chirs, put the validation code (the code with the alert) in the `myState` function as well.

Comment: @Chirs, now the `alert` part is within `function confirmReview(formObj)` (good, I guess), but `function myState` is also defined *within* `function confirmReview(formObj)`, hence will no longer be found by `onchange="myState(this.value);"` Also note that `confirmReview` should return `true` or `false`. See [Show me a Simple javascript onSubmit handler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897360/show-me-a-simple-javascript-onsubmit-handler). PLEASE NOTE: by changing your question, you've also made imulsion's answer outdated. That's not nice. Note we're not a forum; please read About and FAQ.