# Call a JavaScript function before an action in an HTML form

Tags: javascript, html

Can I intercept a form submit action and do some JavaScript function before sending it to [POST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_%28HTTP%29) or [GET](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_methods)?

For example:

```
<form action="something.php" method="post">
     <input type="text" value="Some data"/>
     <input ... ... ... />
     <input type="submit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

Is there a way I can call a JavaScript function before calling action when I click the submit button?

```
javascriptFunction();
// Now go to form action...
```

Comment: The onSubmit event is what you're looking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/5897360/2182349

Comment: Possible duplicate of [before form submit call function javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731265/before-form-submit-call-function-javascript)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<form action="something.php" method="post" onsubmit="return myFunction()">
     <input type="text" value="Some data"/>
     <input ... ... ... />
     <input type="submit" value="Send"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {

        // Do something here

        // If you want to submit form
        return true;

        // If you don't want to submit
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to add an onclick event to the button

```
onclick="yourfunction()"
```

and submit the form at the end of the function

```
document.getElementById("yourform").submit()
```

Comment: Looks a cool workaround for calling a form from external buttons! Thanks :)